# Extracting data points within the hexbins and the contour line

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density

I use the following code to create hexbins and a kde contour line. It colours each hexbin with the average 'Score' values of data points.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read the CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',', header=0)

####  Columns in the data.csv file [PC1,PC2,Index,Score]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5, 5))

# Plot PC1 vs PC2
hb = axes.hexbin(data['PC1'], data['PC2'], gridsize=30, C=data['Score'], reduce_C_function=np.mean, cmap="coolwarm")
cb = plt.colorbar(hb, ax=axes)
kde = sns.kdeplot(data=data, x='PC1', y='PC2', fill=False, cmap="mako", levels=1, thresh=0.5)
axes.set_title('PC1 vs PC2')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('plot.svg')
plt.clf()
```

Here is the plot below. Here I am trying to extract 'Index' value for each data point within the contour line and 10 hexbins having the lowest average value.
I have tried the following code for extracting data-points within the contour but it give empty data.

```
# Obtain the contour level values
contour_values = kde.collections[0].get_paths()[0].vertices

PC1_values = contour_values[:, 0]
PC2_values = contour_values[:, 1]

contour_level_threshold = 0.5

points_within_contour = []
for i in range(len(PC1_values)):
    if kde.collections[0].get_array()[i] >= contour_level_threshold:
        points_within_contour.append((PC1_values[i], PC2_values[i]))

points_within_contour = np.array(points_within_contour)
```

Also, I can get hexbins having the lowest average using the following but I could not figure out how to get datapoints within the hexbins.

```
hexbin_means = hb.get_array()
sorted_indices = np.argsort(hexbin_means)

# Top 10 hexbins with the lowest mean values
top_10_indices = sorted_indices[:10]
```

[image]